# Length in Datatable is not shown correctly

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables version 1.9.

I am redrawing my datatable after adding data to it. It is redrawing correctly, with the page number and the starting record which I wanted.

**The only issue is it is not showing the value correctly in the display record drop down, which I am setting/changing after redrawing, by default it showing 10 only even though I am setting it to 20.**

I am able to see 20 records in my Datatable, which is correct, but the value which appears in Display record drop down is 10.

```js
var xyz = bill_ov_np.selected.table.fnSettings();

xyz._iDisplayLength = info.iLength;
xyz._iDisplayStart  = info.iStart;                    
xyz._iDisplayEnd    = info.iEnd;

xyz.oApi._fnDraw(xyz);
```

NOTE : `info` is the variable in which I am storing previous pagination details and after redrawing the datatable I am using this variable to set previous details for datatable.

Comment: @Gyrocode: good edit. FYI, if you see "urgent" and "please help", these can be removed along with thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use `fnDraw(false)` to redraw the table and keep current page and page length intact. See [`fnDraw`](http://legacy.datatables.net/api#fnDraw) API method for more information.

```
var table = bill_ov_np.selected.table;
table.fnDraw(false);
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60wm0txz/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response .
But when I use  this function after fnAddData it again goes back to first page.
What may be the problem.

Comment: When I use this without fnAddData then it works perfectly and preserves its previous state.